# Apple Airport Extreme Wireless Card M8881 Connectivity Issue

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

I bought a Apple Airport Extreme Wireless Card M8881 with the antenna for my old Power Mac G5 1.6 Ghz.  The computer is running OS X 10.4.  The card works and I can connect to my dlink 802.11g wireless router using WPA2/AES encryption.  The problem is that the connection has intermittent connectivity issues.  When the issue occurs the signal bars for the connection drop to one or two bars and the performance of the connection suffers greatly.  The computer isn't far from the wireless router.  I have a laptop at the desk where the mac is and it does not have any issues.  I'm not sure what it might be? Updated drivers? Firmware? Let me know if I forgot any important information.

Comment: I bought a cable to bring the antennae out from behind the computer and in the line of site of the wireless router. The computer still has random connectivity issues. A reboot fixes the problem. Ideas